# RespondCMS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Error

Tags: respondcms

I am using DigitalOcean and followed the guide to setup already,

Here is the link: http://icebreakwl.com/
But there is an error that stopping me from going further..

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.icebreakwl.com/api/site/validate/id. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource..."

Any expert here please?

Answer (score 1):

Respond uses the domain in settings to created an allowed list of origins. So, you need to have your domain (http://icebreakwl.com) set correctly in Respond's settings.

Comment: Okay, when I set the subdomain `site.example.com` as my Domain, CORS throws no error. Another issues is now this message, which comes when I want to load the languages: `Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_AUTH in /respond5/app/api/libs/Utilities.php on line 543 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /respond5/app/api/libs/Utilities.php:543) in /respond5/app/api/vendor/peej/tonic/src/Tonic/Response.php on line 136 ["de","en"]"`
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Okay, you already fixed this in your dev-branch. Should have checked this before. This should be a hotfix for your stable branch ;-) Replacing line 543 in Utilities.php with this one fixes the problem: `$auth = array_key_exists('HTTP_X_AUTH', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_AUTH'] : '';`